# NavigationDrawer in one of the Fragments of MainActivity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, uinavigationcontroller, navigation-drawer

I have an app that has one MainActivity with BottomNavigation which switches between three Fragments (Fragment 1, 2, 3) as shown in the picture.

[image]

In Fragment 3 I want to have a NavigationDrawer which can switch between 3 items, my question is how do I implement this? I've searched for a while but haven't found exactly my case explanation, though this design can be often found in many popular social apps. What should be the NavHostFragment, where do initialize NavController? And also, **those 3 items should also be fragments?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented the navigation Behavior in the following project that mimics your requirement

It should be a good starting point for you.

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**GITHUB REPO**  **https://github.com/usman14/NavigationComponent**

Comment: Yes, this perfectly works. But if I want to have a custom toolbar in each fragment, am I able to modify it within the fragment itself or I have to manipulate it through MainActivity?

Comment: @EnverUmerov you can modify it within fragment. I just pushed a commit. It should serve as an example for u. https://github.com/usman14/AndroidNavigationComponent/commit/c2277e319accfbfe3a7c4fad398f1603d6a9853c

Comment: alright, thank you so much! I've spent quite a large amount of time figuring out how to structure my project, may God bless you!